# grep, awk and sed alternatives for python?

Tags: python-3.x, awk, sed, python-re

```
os.system(r"grep -R 'Webpage\|Thumbnail' tmp | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | sed '1~2s/\(.*\)/]\[img]\1\[\/img]\[\/URL]/g ; N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/ ; s/^/\[URL=/' | tr -d '[:space:]' > ./" + t + ".files/bbcode.txt")
```

What its doing, grep lines with Keywords in tmp > awk split at space delimiter to get everything after the keywords > sed add "[img]" at start and "[/img][/URL]" at the end of every line > sed add "[URL=" to start and "]" at the end of every second line > move all odd lines to beginning of all even lines > remove all spaces and merge into one big line.

Please can someone point me in the right direction to do this in python?

Comment: You need to provide clear sample input and clear expected output. Otherwise we are left guessing at what your input and wanted output are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple stab at a Python replacement.

- `grep -R` will recursively search regular files in the destination directory. This can be replaced with `os.walk('tmp')`. Remember that the third result from `os.walk` is *just* the file names; you have to glue back the directory in front of each one.
- Fields are generally numbered starting with 1 in the Unix command-line tools, while Python's indexing is zero-based. So the second field from the line is `line.split(' ')[1]`, not `line.split(' ')[2]`
- Without access to your files, I had to guess what the `sed` script is really receiving as input. I'm assuming that every second output is a "Webpage" one and every other is a "Thumbnail" one.

Tangentially, piping Awk to `sed` and `tr` is basically [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); Awk can do everything those two tools can do all by itself (though a nontrivial `sed` script might be hard to reimplement in Awk -- but this is not an example of that. `1~2` is a GNU `sed` extension so this was never very portable to begin with, and would be a lot easier to read and understand in Awk.). Conversely, splitting on a single space with Awk is kind of overkill; `cut -d ' ' -f2` would be a more economical and succinct way to do that.

```py
import os

with open(t + ".files/bbcode.txt", "w") as bbcode:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('tmp'):
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as lines:
                idx = 0
                for line in lines:
                    if 'Webpage' in line or 'Thumbnail' in line:
                        idx += 1
                        field = line.split(' ')[1]
                        if idx % 2 == 1:
                            thumb = field
                            next
                        bbcode.write(
                            '[URL=%s][img]%s[/img][/URL]' % (field, thumb))
```

The decision to collect all output on a single long line is dubious; could you perhaps be persuaded to add a final `\n` to the `write` format string?